# Export AutoCad 2017 layer (with lines, blocks, and text) to GIS shapefile

Tags: qgis, export, autocad

How can I convert (export?) a DWG block into a GIS shapefile so that the block's insertion point will become a point in the shapefile and the block's text attribute will carry over as an attribute in the shapefile?

Comment: Online conversion is not an option.

Comment: shapefile can only have one type (point, polyline, polygon) you will need to export to these different types. I know software (FME, GDAL) can manipulate your data to do this. It that an option?

Comment: If you drag and drop the block (saved as dwg) from Catalog, the types(points, polylines etc) will be separated. If you take a look at the attribute tables, you will see how fields and attributes are translated. May give you other ideas to get what you are after.

Comment: I would try to export the Block info from AutoCad to a txt or csv, then import into QGIS as Points.

Comment: I am sorry that I don't have any experience with GIS and my Cad skills may not be advanced. Some details: layers to be exported to QGIS have lines that represent pipes, blocks that include both plain text (not a CAD attribute) W plus symbol (like valve).

Comment: Question: 1) Can AutoCad safe as shape files? Or GIS software may be use. Looking for auto feature that does not require manipulation of the original drawing/layer in other words selecting manually blocks. 2) the GIS consultant does not care to see the blocks, just wants insertion point location.

Comment: Please clarify if the point, polyline, polygon separation is done in CAD or GIS software. Thanks!

Comment: Not clear how to export multiple blocks from CAD layer that would give GIS consultant only the insertion point.

Comment: @Bay: You can disregard my earlier comment -- I just assumed you are working with ArcMap. Your tags say QGIS.

Comment: @Bay https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf explains the shapefile format in detail, simple you need to have more files for conversion.

Comment: There is a DATAEXTRACTION command in autocad that could work with the suggestion by @klewis. You could get XY coordinates for the insertion point.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].